# ShouldI continue to use a while loop switch or do for a ask and answer program or should I use switch?

Tags: c++, loops

I am test out a question/answer program and relatively new to c++. I am trying to create a question/answer and so far using the while loop to check if the answer is true it will retuen the problem is if the question is wrong if the  here is my code:

```
  while(input1 == answer1)
{
cout << "Your answer is correct!\n";
answer_correct += 1;
break;
}
while(answer_correct = 0 )
{
cout << "Correct Answer is:\n" << answer1 << "\n";
break;
}
```

for ZETA
original code:

```
 if (input3 == answer3)
{
cout << "Your answer is correct!";
answer_correct += 1;
}
else
{
cout << "Correct Answer is:\n" << answer3;
}
```

all if statements below this one are return false and display the answers below when input == to answer
Now I need to make it not show the correct answer using if statements. I am probably confused would someone educate me on a proper loop to use?

Comment: Those `while` loops should be `if` statements. All they're doing is checking a condition, and executing once if that condition is true. Also, the second one is missing an `=` in the condition.

Comment: Actually already tried its using multiple questions and when answered correctly it returns everything else false

Comment: The code you added is definitely not enough. It's not clear what your program does, how many input the user has to provide, etc. Please post your complete code, shortened to the essentials of your problem. See also http://sscce.org

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason why you don't use a `if-else` statement?

```
if(input1 == answer1)
{
    cout << "Your answer is correct!\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Correct Answer is:\n" << answer1 << "\n";
}
```

#### Explanation

The block/statement following the `if(condition)` will only be executed if and only if the `condition` is true. An `else` following an `if` will only be executed if and only if the  preceding `if` failed.

See also:

- [CPP: Control Structures](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)

Comment: I am using multiple question and when input returns true all other questions return false

Comment: @General_Vladimir: I don't understand - maybe you should post more code - have you tried `if(input1 == answer1 || input1 == answer2 || ...)`?